# Choose the calendars appearing in the GNOME shell panel

Tags: gnome-shell, calendar

When clicking the clock, or date and time, in the Panel of GNOME shell, a popup displays a calendar browsable for events from connected or local calendars. (As far as I know, the date is fetched from the evolution-data-server.) An account may provide multiple different calendars.

In the gnome-calendar app, one can choose which calendars to display via a menu button. Optimally, I would like for the calendar application to show all calendars while only showing a few in the panel applet. Is is possible to choose the calendars showing up in the panel? If yes, where does the option hide?

Comment: Here's the [Gnome Calendar](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Calendar/Features) webpage  ... I don't use gnome or evolution ... prefer very plain openbox as processor cycles are precious for calculations and simulations... However, it seems from the screenshots that there is a calendar selection gui.